# Root and instance creator password?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I use the Google Compute Engine Web Console to remote into my instance. I can perform root operations using "sudo", but what if I wanted to "su" to root?

I created a user "test", and now want to log-in as "test" -- this doesn't work as I have not yet generated SSH keys. Where do I find these keys for instance creator and/or root as well?

Also, I used a Debian image, but few commands appear to be installed by default. For instance, locate, updatedb, etc are missing? How do I get these?

Comment: You might want to take a moment to clarify your question. Tags are for categorization, not to make up for missing details in the post body. Carefully and clearly explain what you're trying to do, what you tried, and what isn't working. This will get you the best answers possible. Good luck!

Comment: Edited this just a bit, but you might clarify what you mean in the second paragraph?  Do you mean "instance creator" as in the person who created the compute engine instance?  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You asked several questions in a single post; I'll answer them in order.

> (1) *I use the Google Compute Engine Web Console to remote into my instance. I can perform root operations using "sudo", but what if I wanted to "su" to root?*

Use: `sudo su -`

---

> (2) *I created a user "test", and now want to log-in as "test" -- this doesn't work as I have not yet generated SSH keys. Where do I find these keys for instance creator and/or root as well?*

You can ssh via [`gcloud compute ssh`](https://developers.google.com/cloud/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh) or by clicking on the "SSH" button on the web UI, and then run: `sudo su test`.

---

> (3) *Also, I used a Debian image, but few commands appear to be installed by default. For instance, locate, updatedb, etc are missing? How do I get these?*

To install missing packages, you'll have to use the standard Debian command `apt-get` to install the packages, e.g.:

```
$ sudo apt-get install [name-of-package]
```

To find a package name using keywords, use:

```
$ apt-cache search [keyword]
```

---

***Note:*** the first thing you want to do on a brand-new instance is to update your package metadata cache by running:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) I managed to get test account to login and see that locate package was not installed *sounds like mlocate succeeded it??) Anyway is "sudo su -" a function of su? I have always setup debian manually an forced to enter a root password and su directly as i would any user

Comment: @Alex.Barylski yes, looks like [mlocate](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/mlocate) is intended as a replacement for [locate](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/locate) but both are available. `sudo su -` works without a password on these systems by design, so that users don't share a single root password, but use their own separate logins instead. If I'm not understanding your question, please rephrase.

Answer (score 0):

https://cloud.google.com/solutions/set-up-postgres

The above link helped me get over a similar issue described above but in the postgres user setup context. Wasn't covered in any of the other posts so thought to share here.

Comment: Please post an answer, not just a link. Links expire, and the SO search doesn't search the contents of links so if someone searches for this issue they won't find your answer.